# Matplotlib Plot with Finer tick marks but no labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, axes

[image]I am trying to produce a plot where I have customized axis ticks on both x and y axis. But like in a scale, I would like to have the finer tick marks present while the tick markings only on the bigger values. Like shown in the attached plot(which is similar to what I want).

so I tried :

```
ax.tick_params(labeltop=True, labelright=True)
```

Because I need the ticks on all 4 sides. and then I would do something like this :

```
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
```

and then specify the range :

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(-1.20, -0.79, 0.04))
plt.yticks(np.arange(-1.0,1.2, 0.1))
```

But I would like the numerical markings every 5th position (or every 5th tick)

Comment: I think you are looking for "minor ticks" https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/major_minor_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's My solution : (thanks @Diziet)

```
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,AutoMinorLocator)   
# Plotting codes go in here
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')# Ticks on all 4 sides                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
plt.xticks(np.arange(-1.21, -0.79, 0.04)) # Axes ranges                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
plt.yticks(np.arange(-0.9,0.9, 0.1))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.05)) # Intervals for major x-ticks                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator()) # Minor ticks : Automatic filling based on the ytick range                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.3))  # For y-ticks                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
```

Attached is the Final product[image: Plot with finer ticks]